# SQL Server /Azure Portal give default (sysadmin) QUERYTRACEON permission

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, permissions

**Description**

I am trying to run `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 460)` command on sql server. However, I have not been able to. I tried following several recommendations but each time there is a permission error.

**Tried**

- Running it from the Sysadmin account
- Creating stored procedure with it in
- Adding new user (Permissions issues when I try to add to admin group)

I keep getting the following error

> User 'default_admin' does not have permission to run DBCC TRACEON.

This is definitely the user that is the sysadmin when you create the DBA trhough auzre.

**Question**

How do you give the user permission. A Query would be ideal that I can run on the master table.

Comment: How did you create the user? Can you show us your create statements? Did you mean you run the OPTION query and get the permission issues both on SQL server and Azure SQL server Portal?

Comment: I created my user through Azure Portal when the database was created. I mean whenever I run the QUERYTRACEON command I get a permission denied. I run the command through Microsoft SQL Server Manager - which is connected to my Azure SQL DB

Comment: Azure SQL single database or managed instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Azure SQL database(single database), [DBCC TRACEON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) is not supported.

[image]

So you can not run `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 460)` command on Azure SQL DB.

It will give you the error:

[image]

Hope this helps.